# How to easily do an async REST request in Perl?

Tags: perl, rest, asynchronous

I am currently in the throes of writing a plugin for Bugzilla, and so all of the code needs to be written in Perl. I have everything working quite nicely, however there are a few places where I know I need to do multiple requests to the same REST server, and, given that it might be distant network wise, I would like to be able to send several requests, and then wait for them all to come back, rather than do the Stop-And-Wait Send/Wait/Send/Wait.

Using [REST::Client](http://search.cpan.org/~mcrawfor/REST-Client-88/lib/REST/Client.pm) allows for very easy access to REST client functionality, which is what I am currently using. The top Google result for `perl sync rest` is [HTTP::Async](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Async/lib/HTTP/Async.pm), but this page doesn't address REST directly, and it is not clear to be how to easily use HTTP::Request to easily process them.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Mojo::UserAgent is a very nice web agent that does async well.